# Is it possible to play audio from a short[] instead of a byte[] with NAudio?

Tags: c#, naudio

I am trying to play audio received over a network which arrives as an array of shorts. I am trying to make this work with a WaveOut object from NAudio, but from what I could find, this only works with a byte[]. So my questions so far are:

- Is it possible to play audio from a short[] instead of a byte[]?
- If so, how would this be done?

It's not much, but what I have now is this (which obviously plays audio from a byte[]):

```
protected override void Write(VoiceSource source, VoicePacket packet)
{
      if (connected)
      {
            try
            {
                dispatcher.Invoke((WriteCallback)provider.Write, packet.Data);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
      }
}
```

Where the `WriteCallback` is defined as:

```
private delegate void WriteCallback(byte[] data);
```

The provider I am writing to is an implementation of the `IWaveProvider` interface.

---

### Edit

I've tried the "trick" Mark told me about, with my Interface looking like this:

```
interface ISampleBuffer {
    byte[] Bytes { get; set; }
    short[] Shorts { get; set; }
}
```

And the buffer struct looking like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 2)]
public struct SampleBuffer : ISampleBuffer
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    private byte[] bytes;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    private short[] shorts;
    public byte[] Bytes { get { return bytes; } set { bytes = value; } }
    public short[] Shorts { get { return shorts; } set { shorts = value; } }
}
```

I've implemented this buffer like so:

```
short[] audio = decoder.Decode(packet.Data);
buffer.Bytes = new byte[audio.Length * 2];
buffer.Shorts = audio;
dispatcher.Invoke((WriteCallback)provider.Write, buffer.Bytes);
```

However, whenever I run this setup, I get a stacktrace with the following exception in my logs:

`Object of type 'System.Int16[]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Byte[]'.`

Is there something wrong with how I implemented this?

Comment: You're misunderstanding what `byte[]` and `short[]` actually represent. An array is a _reference type_, so a variable of type `byte[]` is actually a pointer to somewhere else on the heap. To do something like this, you need to use a `fixed` field in an unsafe struct, and you need to know the size of the array at compile time.

Comment: The size of the array is known at compile time. The audio I get comes in short arrays of 24o length. So it should be possible. What would I need to change for it to work?

Comment: Use a fixed buffer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya%28v=VS.100%29.aspx. You'll have to use pointers & other badness to turn it into an array. Although I get the feeling you're approaching the problem from the wrong angle, if you're having to resort to those...

Comment: Well, due to the complexity to implement it, I'd rather not use it. But I'm just exploring all angles to see what works. I've tried your approach, which technically works without a hitch. Practically though, I don't hear a thing. No audio is being played.

Comment: should be other way round. buffer.Shorts = decoder.Decode... and then pass buffer.Bytes into your function

Comment: also without knowing what your WriteCallback does I can't say whether the WaveBuffer trick will work for your app

Answer (score 3):

NAudio includes a clever trick (or dirty hack depending on your point of view), that allows you to "cast" from a `short[]` to `byte[]`. It is called the `WaveBuffer` class and works by using a struct with an explicit layout. Simply write into the `ShortBuffer` property and read out of the `ByteBuffer` property.

I [blogged](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2008/06/wavebuffer-casting-byte-arrays-to-float.html) about it a while ago. It has worked reliably for several years now, and saves the overhead of using `Buffer.BlockCopy`.

Comment: Do you have a concrete example of use for the class? I can't really figure out how to implement the IWaveBuffer interface... :S

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the NAudio bit, but I can help you with converting a `short[]` to a `byte[]`. `Buffer.BlockCopy` might be useful here, as that can copy bytes between arrays of different types:

```
 short[] shortArray = ...
 byte[] byteArray = new byte[shortArray.Length*2];
 Buffer.BlockCopy(shortArray, 0, byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
```

however, you might get into endian problems. You'll need to try it and see what happens. If you need to swap the two bytes comprising a single short, you can swap it manually:

```
 for (int i=0; i<byteArray.Length; i += 2) {
     byte b = byteArray[i];
     byteArray[i] = byteArray[i+1];
     byteArray[i] = b;
 }
```

Alternatively, if you want things a bit neater, and don't want to worry about endian conversions, you could use a `BinaryWriter` to do the conversion for you:

```
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(new MemoryStream(shortArray.Length*2));
foreach (short s in shortArray)
    writer.Write(s);

byte[] byteArray = ((MemoryStream)writer.BaseStream).ToArray();
```

Comment: +1, Good answer, and Buffer.BlockCopy is the "correct" way to do this in .NET, although NAudio does have a trick up its sleeve which I have written about in another answer.

Comment: I've tried this, and it works without any complaint from the program's side of view. The only problem I do get is that I get no audio at all...

Comment: After once more trying your last suggestion, I am able to get audio. However, what comes out of the speakers nowhere resembles the input I give it. Even when I simply blow into the mic, the output stutters, slightly echoes... I knew it would be difficult to get this stuff working, but not this difficult...